# How to migrate to ES6 a little by little?

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I have a lot of old JavaScript. I have yesterday started using webpack to help split up JavaScript into files that are seperated and it works. I want to upgrade the code to ES6, and having all the JavaScripts seperate I hope to upgrade the coding one file at a time.

How best do I make this? I understand that Babel is required, but it is important that I can mix old JavaScripts with new ES6 scripts while upgrading the code, and they happily work together.

Please accept my apologies for my bad English, and thank you very much for any advice you can send.

Comment: What sort of module definitions does your old code use?

Comment: Hello @bebraw. I have looked, and the CommonJS is the correct answer. Not AMD. I am sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old JS code will already work in ES6+/Babel, you could just make slight modifications to variables, methods and classes to **export** them and make them available in other files. 
https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#modules

Comment: OK! So I send all scripts into Babel and it can understand the scripts that are the JavaScript and the scripts that are the ES6 and the two are happy together?

Comment: Hello again @glued. Thankyou for your answer. Is it that I need to tell Babel which file is which language or is it able to decide language for me?

Comment: You don't need to tell babel anything. Just write code like normal and if you see an opportunity to do something the ES6 way in your existing code, give it a shot.